# how to prevent people from using ssh from a machine, but allow ssh in

Tags: ssh

Somehow a user has been gaining access to my server. I have blocked ssh for all but a few users I trust and who absolutely need ssh access (used `AllowUsers` in sshd_config). In the event that one of them has been hacked, how can I block them from sshing out of the server? There is no reason to ssh out of the server they access.
Any advice?

Comment: You can block outgoing connections to port 22, either locally using ip tables, or better blocking then in the firewall/gateway if possible.

Comment: This will not protect your server from break-ins though. It's analogous to locking *one* exit door from inside so that only key holders can leave – but it has no effect on people trying to come in through the entrance and people using other exit doors.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be remove `openssh-clients` package. Second possibility is to block the outgoing traffic to port 22 as proposed in comments in `iptables`.

But none of that will solve the issue if the users want to `ssh` to different port or they will download/install/create `ssh` client binary in their home directory (which is probably writable for them).

Without clarifying what you really want, it is too broad to answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an easy approach to prohibit users running the ssh client. If the users gain root access there is no way, I guess.

As long as they are "normal" user, in [this article](https://serverfault.com/questions/8820/preventing-users-from-running-certain-programs/8826#8826) are some good hints for a solution.